# HTTP service fired before the parameter initialized

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous, rxjs

I use angular 10 in my project.
I have nested HTTP calls in the ngOnInit function here how it looks:

```
ngOnInit(): void  {
  
  let communetyid;
  
    this.route.data.subscribe(data => { 
      this.route.params.subscribe(params => { 
        
      if(data.category === "code")
      {
        this.dataService.getCode(params.code)
          .subscribe(resp => { communetyid = resp.results.communityId });
      }
      else  
      {
        communetyid = params.id
      }

      this.dataService.getCommunityById(communetyid)
        .subscribe(response => { this.community = response.results; 
        
            ///other http calls
        
       }) 
     })
   })
})
```

As you can see in the code above the `dataService.getCommunityById` get as parameter communetyid the communetyid gets value inside if statment. Because of asynchronous `dataService.getCommunityById` function triggered before communityid get value and I get the error in the console.

How can I change the code that when `dataService.getCommunityById` is fired the value communetyid will be initialized.

I know that I can copy `dataService.getCommunityById` inside subscribe of the `dataService.getCode` but I want to prevent code duplication.

Comment: You can find a detailed solution for your case and common examples of use of RxJs with Http  [in this article](https://medium.com/better-programming/rxjs-patterns-emerging-from-stackoverflow-asynchronous-api-calls-as-streams-in-the-real-world-ef636c9af19a)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to following :-

```
ngOnInit(): void  {
  
  let communetyid;
  
    this.route.data.subscribe(data => { 
      this.route.params.subscribe(params => { 
        
      const communityIdObs = date.category === 'code' ? this.dataService.getCode(params.code).pipe(map(resp => resp.results.communityId)) : of(params.id);
      communityIdObs.pipe(mergeMap(res => {
         return this.dataService.getCommunityById(communetyid);
      }).subscribe(response => { 
            this.community = response.results; 
            ///other http calls
      });
})
```

Mergemap operator will keep your calls in sequence and i have also modified the code to make it shorter.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the original pattern you were using (nesting subscriptions), you should just move "getCommunityById" http call into "dataService.getCode" callback, and it will work. Key point here is to understand that "dataService.getCode" will return an observable (data that is not already there) and your else branch works with value that is already there (params.id).
Right way to solve this issue is to use concatMap() inside of a pipe() and to chain these operations. In the concatMap() callback you will handle your if-else branch logic where you will return either this.dataService.getCode or Observable.of(params.id) and than in the next concatMap() you will use this value as an argument for this.dataService.getCommunityById.

Comment: Tomov, thank you for the post.  Can you please show example?

Answer (score 1):

You can consider chaining your `Observables` using higher order `operators`

```typescript
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private dataService: DataService
  ) {}

  // Extract Parameters from the Activated Route
  params$ = this.route.paramMap.pipe(
    map(params => ({
      id: params.get("id"),
      code: params.get("code"),
      category: params.get("category")
    }))
  );

  // Get Community Id
  communityId$ = this.params$.pipe(
    mergeMap(({ category, code, id }) =>
      category === "code"
        ? this.dataService
            .getCode(code)
            .pipe(map(({ results }) => results.communityId))
        : of(id)
    )
  );

  // Get Community
  community$ = this.communityId$.pipe(
    switchMap((communetyId) => this.dataService.getCommunityById(communetyId))
  )

  ngOnInit() {
    this.community$.subscribe({
      next: console.log
    });
  }
}
```

### Code explanation

#### Extract Parameters

```
  params$ = this.route.paramMap.pipe(
    map(params => ({
      id: params.get("id"),
      code: params.get("code"),
      category: params.get("category")
    }))
  );
```

I am using `paramMap` to extract parameters from the `ActivatedRoute`. From Angular Docs, `params` is deprecated (Or to be deprecated)

> `ActivatedRoute` contains two properties that are less capable than their replacements and may be deprecated in a future Angular version.

The next step we define a  property `communityId` whose value is dependent on mapping the `params` by checking the `category` property. I am using `mergeMap` operator to merge the the subscription of `params$` to `communityId$`.

The final steps is to get `community$`. Here we use `switchMap`. We wouldn't want to continue with an initial request if a new request has been made hence this operator is the most suitable here

[See a sample demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dtnxkc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fchild%2Fchild.component.ts)

Comment: I think this works as expected only if "code" is a string of length 1, as in the example. The reason is in how `mergeMap` is used. `mergeMap` wants, as parameter, a function that returns an Observable. In the solution the proposed, the function passed as parameter to `mergeMap` is `{ category, code, id }) => category === "code" ? this.dataService.getCode(code).pipe(map(({ results }) => results.communityId)) : id` which returns either an Observable or a string. But a string is an Observable which emits each of its chars. You can see this in action if you try with a `code` with like "123".

Comment: @Picci good observation, I have updated the solution

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use `concatMap` Operator

To transform one response to parameters required for the consecutive request you use `concatMap`

Operator `concatMap()` internally subscribes to the Observable returned the from its projection function and waits until it completes while re-emitting all its values.

Here is an example

```
function mockHTTPRequest(url) {
    return Observable.of(`Response from ${url}`)
      .delay(1000);
}

let urls = ['url-1', 'url-2', 'url-3', 'url-4'];
let start = (new Date()).getTime();

Observable.from(urls)
  .concatMap(url => mockHTTPRequest(url))
  .timestamp()
  .map(stamp => [stamp.timestamp - start, stamp.value])
  .subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

Comment: please can you provide an example related  to the posted code.

Comment: `concatMap` is the operator to use in such cases. You can read more details and find inspiration for similar cases [in this article](https://medium.com/better-programming/rxjs-patterns-emerging-from-stackoverflow-asynchronous-api-calls-as-streams-in-the-real-world-ef636c9af19a)

Answer (score 0):

Eventhough you can use rxjs for chaining the observables. There is another simple approach to solve your issue. If you put anything inside the subscription of an observable it gets executed, so you need to move it outside as a separate function. It should help you in prevention of calling your *dataService.getCommunityById* function.

```
ngOnInit(): void  {

let communetyid;

this.route.data.subscribe(data => { 
  this.route.params.subscribe(params => { 
    
  if(data.category === "code")
  {
    this.dataService.getCode(params.code)
      .subscribe((resp) => 
      { 
          communetyid = resp.results.communityId;
          getCommunityData(communetyid);
    });
  }
  else  
  {
    communetyid = params.id;
    getCommunityData(communetyid);
  }

  })
 })  
})

getCommunityData(communetyid) {
  this.dataService.getCommunityById(communetyid)
  .subscribe(response => { 
     this.community = response.results;
     //other http calls
  })
}
```

This is an alternate approach to using rxjs, this is just easier to understand. You can also use rxjs operators like *concatMap*, *of* as suggested by **Medhat Mahmoud** and **Muhammet Can TONBUL**.